# python xml element.firstChild doesn't return Element

Tags: python, xml

I would like o do something like this:

```
    simpleType = el.firstChild
    if simpleType:
        print simpleType.getAttribute("base")
```

where el is Element.
When I try to run it, I get error:

```
AttributeError: Text instance has no attribute 'getAttribute'
```

I am assuming that first child is returning a Node. How can I get an Element instead of this?
Here is wider context:

```
def printTypes(typeName, DOMTree):

elements = DOMTree.getElementsByTagName("xsd:simpleType")
simpleType = None
for el in elements:
    if el.getAttribute("name") == typeName :
        simpleType = el.firstChild
        if simpleType:
            print simpleType.getAttribute("base")
        break
```

And an exaple ox the xml:

```
<xsd:element name="VictimInformation" type="VictimInformationType"/>
<xsd:simpleType name="VictimInformationType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `print simpleType`?

Comment: You should probably check if simpleType is not None.

Comment: From the error message it looks like `simpleType` is a string. Check the type of `el.firstChild` and see if it's what you're expecting.

Comment: @dusan it's <DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
for c in el.childNodes:
    if c.nodeType != node.TEXT_NODE:
```

Answer (score 0):

My psychic powers tell me the input is like

```
<el>text<simpleType base="val" /></el>
```

Therefore, the first child element of `<el>` is the Text `text`(maybe even just spaces). You can just iterate over the `childNodes` property like this:

```
for c in el.childNodes:
    if c.tagName == 'simpleType':
        print c.getAttribute('base')
        break
```

As a side effect, this will make your application compatible with future/third-party extensions of the format.